# comparing a string with a panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This is how my dataframe looks like:

```
df2.head()
             brand  brand_len
3   [delta]         1        
5   [whirlpool]     1        
11  [toro]          1        
15  [insinkerator]  1        
16  [sunjoy]        1
```

When I want to compare a string `Q=['delta','pandas']` with my df2, I don't get any match. This is how I am doing it:

```
#check for exact similarity
Q = ['delta','pandas']
for q in Q:
    print q
    for brand in df2.brand:
        print brand
        if q==brand:
            print brand
```

This is the output:

```
             brand  brand_len
3   [delta]         1        
5   [whirlpool]     1        
11  [toro]          1        
15  [insinkerator]  1        
16  [sunjoy]        1        
delta
[u'delta']
[u'whirlpool']
[u'toro']
[u'insinkerator']
[u'sunjoy']
```

How can I get rid of the u presented in my brand variable.

Comment: Is there a reason your strings are in a list? Is your column always a single value?

Comment: The u means it's a Unicode string.

Comment: @EdChum yes, the reason is that sometimes my brand consists of more than one  words. I might have something like that ['deck','over'].

Answer (score 1):

Your Strings are Unicode. You can force them to be strings by using *str(x)* function.

Run the following code and you will see what happens:

```
a = u'asd'
print (type(a))
print (type(str(a)))
str(a)
```

Comment: @lbs print str(brand) would still give the same output as print brand